# Python. Django. How to avoid of logging file's body during logging incoming payload. multipart/form-data

Tags: python, regex, django, logging, multipartform-data

**Env:**
python==2.7
Django==1.8.4

**Required:**
When request come with `multipart/form-data` required to replace data of file, but keep all other information.

**Example:**
print `request.data` contains following:

```
--------------------------0a79b890de6a2e8f
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="example.jpeg"
 Content-Type: image/jpeg

 ����JFIFHH��C
 and here is 2MB of bytes
����J��(!1AQqa ���@���P���?�z▒��h�x*iٍ8�
 --------------------------0a79b890de6a2e8f
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_1"

 example_1
 --------------------------0a79b890de6a2e8f
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_2"

 example_2
```

**Expected:**

```
--------------------------0a79b890de6a2e8f
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="example.jpeg"
 Content-Type: image/jpeg

 <file-data>
 --------------------------0a79b890de6a2e8f
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_1"

 example_1
 --------------------------0a79b890de6a2e8f
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_2"

 example_2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
It is definitely not best solution. I guess more solutions could proposed in answers.
But I hope it could help to someone.

Put this class in middlewares(solution is simplified):

```
import logging
import re

RE_PATTERN = r'(?<=; filename=")(.*?)"\\r\\nContent-Type: (.*?)\\r\\n(.*?)((-+)([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)\\r\\nContent-Disposition:)'  # noqa
RE_REPLACE_TO = r'\1"\\r\\nContent-Type: \2\\r\\n\\r\\n<file-data>\\r\\n\4'


class RequestLogger(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    def process_request(self, request):
        formatted_body = re.sub(
            pattern=RE_PATTERN,
            repl=RE_REPLACE_TO,
            string="%r" % request.body).decode('string_escape')
        # or "{!r}".format(request.body)

        self._logger.info('Body: {}'.format(formatted_body))
```